# How to find optimum column values when they affect another column value in time series data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, statistics

Original data frame spans a million rows and has an year's data. Here's top ten rows:

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': {0: '2020-12-08',
  1: '2020-12-08',
  2: '2020-12-08',
  3: '2020-12-08',
  4: '2020-12-08',
  5: '2020-12-08',
  6: '2020-12-08',
  7: '2020-12-08',
  8: '2020-12-08',
  9: '2020-12-08'},
 'points': {0: 200,
  1: 50,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 150,
  5: 200,
  6: 200,
  7: 50,
  8: 100,
  9: 200},
 'count': {0: 19,
  1: 9,
  2: 32,
  3: 28,
  4: 22,
  5: 17,
  6: 22,
  7: 17,
  8: 28,
  9: 24}})
```

If you'd observe the actual whole dataset, you'd see that the 'count' decreases when 'points' is either too high or too low. How to find the optimum value of points? Optimum means the value of points that gives maximum number of counts. Answer might be a high school level mathematics solution.

One possible solution I can think of is to train an ML model using just points as X and count as y, (maybe no train test split), then make a data frame with points 1 to 500 and predict count for each point. Maybe the number of point with most count could be considered as optimum statistically?

This will give me estimated number of counts for, say, 90 points, 106 points and so on.

Comment: "number of..." doesn't say much about optimum. For example : Do you want minimum number of "points" values or minimum of total of points selected to maximize total count etc.? Please clearly mention the requirement for what is considered an optimum selection of "points" values.

Comment: @SomeDude Edited. Optimum means the value of points that gives maximum number of counts.

Comment: Just the value of points? sort counts and take top 10, or 50 or whatever and sum the points. There must be some optimizing constraint that you are looking for.

Comment: if you want to predict `count` based on `points`, you could: 1. use the `count` mean for a partiular `points` value (e.g. the prediction for points 50 would be count (9 + 17)/2 ) 2. Use the latest `count` value for a particular `points` value 3. use logistic regression 4. use a neural network 5. probably a lot more options

Comment: @SomeDude That actually makes most sense.

Comment: @AndrzejO Tried sum instead of mean, for some reason results made more sense, will try logistic and neural network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": {
            0: "2020-12-08",
            1: "2020-12-08",
            2: "2020-12-08",
            3: "2020-12-08",
            4: "2020-12-08",
            5: "2020-12-08",
            6: "2020-12-08",
            7: "2020-12-08",
            8: "2020-12-08",
            9: "2020-12-08",
        },
        "points": {
            0: 200,
            1: 50,
            2: 0,
            3: 0,
            4: 150,
            5: 200,
            6: 200,
            7: 50,
            8: 100,
            9: 200,
        },
        "count": {
            0: 19,
            1: 9,
            2: 32,
            3: 28,
            4: 22,
            5: 17,
            6: 22,
            7: 17,
            8: 28,
            9: 24,
        },
    }
)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df["points"], df["count"], train_size=0.8
)

# Create linear regression object
regr = LinearRegression()

# Create a RobustScaler object
sc = RobustScaler()

# Normalize data
scaled = sc.fit_transform(X_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(scaled, y_train)

# Convert prediction values back to their original scale
test_df = df[df.index.isin(X_test.index)]

scaled_test = sc.transform(X_test.values.reshape(-1, 1))

test_df["Prediction"] = regr.predict(scaled_test)

# Round predictions, and convert values to integers
test_df["Prediction"] = test_df["Prediction"].round(0).astype(int)
test_df

# Prints:
#
#          time  points  count  Prediction
# 0  2020-12-08     200     19          21
# 8  2020-12-08     100     28          20
```